# TypeScript: Conditionally declare the return type of a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I'm writing a React application using TypeScript.

I've written a wrapper for a function that makes an API call:

```
import { ROUTE_CANDIDATES, ROUTE_TWIG_PICK } from "../../../config/constants/routes";
import { pickSchema } from "../../../config/schemas/picks";
import { PickCreateBulkResponse, PickCreateUpdateResponse } from "../../../config/types";
import { postRequest, putRequest } from "../../utils/serverRequests";

interface PickJSON {
  candidate: string;
  picked_int_choice: string;
}

const pickListSchema = [pickSchema];

export const postPickCreate = (
  body: PickJSON | PickJSON[]
): Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse | PickCreateBulkResponse> => {
  if (Array.isArray(body)) {
    return postRequest(ROUTE_CANDIDATES + ROUTE_TWIG_PICK, body, pickListSchema) as Promise<
      PickCreateBulkResponse
    >;
  } else {
    return postRequest(ROUTE_CANDIDATES + ROUTE_TWIG_PICK, body, pickSchema) as Promise<
      PickCreateUpdateResponse
    >;
  }
};
```

As you can see I'm trying to dynamically assert the correct type of the response. Meaning if the function was used with an array, it should return a `Promise<PickCreateBuldResponse>`, whereas if it was used with a single object, it should return `Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse>`. How can I get TypeScript to know what it returns? As you can see above I tried using `as`, but this does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare [function overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
export function postPickCreate(body: PickJSON): Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse>
export function postPickCreate(body: PickJSON[]): Promise<PickCreateBulkResponse>
export function postPickCreate(body: PickJSON | PickJSON[]):
    Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse | PickCreateBulkResponse> {

    if (Array.isArray(body)) {
        return postRequest(ROUTE_CANDIDATES + ROUTE_TWIG_PICK, body, pickListSchema) as
            Promise<PickCreateBulkResponse>;
    } else {
        return postRequest(ROUTE_CANDIDATES + ROUTE_TWIG_PICK, body, pickSchema) as
            Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse>;
    }
}
```

However, since in your case you already know the type of your value at design time and TypeScript does the type checking for you, your best approach is probably to simply separate your functions. That's what you are actually doing inside the function in the `if` block:

```
export function postPickCreate(body: PickJSON): Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse> {
    return postRequest(ROUTE_CANDIDATES + ROUTE_TWIG_PICK, body, pickSchema) as
        Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse>;
}

export function postPickCreateRange(body: PickJSON[]): Promise<PickCreateBulkResponse> {
    return postRequest(ROUTE_CANDIDATES + ROUTE_TWIG_PICK, body, pickListSchema) as
        Promise<PickCreateBulkResponse>;
}
```

Comment: I don't think those `as Promise<PickCreateBulkResponse>` and `as Promise<PickCreateUpdateResponse>` do anything, could just remove them. (Also, function declarations don't have `;` after the body.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Removed the semicolans, thanks. I transferred the `as Promise<>` unchanged from the OP's post, since I don't know what `postRequest` does exactly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks :)

Comment: We don't need to know what `postRequest` does, though, to know we don't need those type assertions. :-) The overloading handles that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: If `postRequest` retuns `any`, we need to assert the type accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! `postRequest` returns an object of the form `{ result: any; entities: any }`. And then eg. `PickCreateBulkResponse` is of the form `{ result: string; entities: { picks: NormalizedData<Pick> } }`. I don't know if that changes your answer somehow.

Comment: Additional question: I thought about seperating the function, too. But the problem is that then each time before I call this function I'd have to determine which one two calls. I would just like to pass it an array and for the function to recognize it, which is why I designed it the way I did in my question. Should I just write a wrapper that accepts both inputs and then returns on of your respective suggested functions based on the if statement?

Comment: @Sefe - The documentation doesn't seem to bear that out, see the example in the link I added to your answer. Am I missing something? (Genuine question, I'm still fairly naive with TypeScript.)

Comment: @J.Hesters - But if you have an array, you know which one to call, so...? (The answer to your question, though, is no - if you want to keep using one function for this, just use the branch within the function as you have done.)

Comment: @J.Hesters: Thanks for the info. Since the return type of `postRequest` is not compatible with the return type of your method, you need the type assertion. And if you don't know the input type, you should go for overloading as a solution. Technically you don't need the overload if you have no case where you are sure about the input type. You will need a type guard for the return value in any case.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I learned a lot today :) Just for clarification: my main goal with this was that my linter knows what's up. So that if I call the function with an array it automatically knows that the Promise will resolve with a `PickCreateBulkResponse` or a `PickCreateUpdateResponse` if I just put in an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) to correctly type the function.

```
interface Foo {}

interface BarMany { many: string; }
interface BarOne { one: string; }

interface BazFunc {
    (foo: Foo[]): BarMany;
    (foo: Foo): BarOne;
}

const baz: BazFunc = (foo) => {
    if(Array.isArray(foo)) {
    return { many: "flibble" };
  } else {
      return { one: "flibble" };
  }
};

var one = baz({});
var many = baz([]);
```

Here's a jsFiddle of that in action: https://jsfiddle.net/z4vo5u5d/22392/

And the output:

```
one - One: flibble, Many: undefined
many - One: undefined, Many: flibble
```